# database.yml proxy? or equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, proxy

I am looking for a way to run a rails server on one network that is driven by a database on a different network, where both are separated by a proxy server. I have the proxy server URL.

I have the rails server connecting via the MySQL database network's external IP address, via port forwarding on 3306, and so can connect between the networks just fine if I'm not behind the proxy. Setting the proxy is the problem

Network topology:

```
{rail server} -> {proxy server controls all external traffic} -> {mysql database}
```

I was hoping I could put something like this in the database.yml file (see proxy part) ->

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: users
  username: root
  password: ***
  host: *ip-address*
  port: 3306
  proxy: *proxy-url*
```

This does not work. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what is exactly the "proxy" machine? seems like you need a Gateway machine, and not a proxy.

Comment: The proxy server is the controlling server on my university's network. The database is on a server outside that network.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

host: host name. (xyz.com)

port: 80 (or whatever)

proxy_host: ABC.lan.flt

proxy_port: 3122 (what ever is the port of the proxy)

Apart from this username password adapter database name are also required.